# Making OAuth Connected Apps work if current Admin User gets inactivated

Tags: integration, connected-apps, oauth, system-admin

In our Production instance we have deactivated a System Administrator and while clearing all dependencies we have found a lot of "OAuth Connected Apps" under his user account. Our understanding is these might be the external application references that are connected with Salesforce authorized by the System Administrator.

After deactivating the Admin user, from login history, we see all those applications are being failed to connect with salesforce as the user is inactive. We identified a few of the applications that are required to be connected with Salesforce for business reasons like sharing data with the salesforce application.

Is there any way we can have these connected apps run/ authenticate in the context of other identified admin user so that the sync can continue without fail?

Comment: Revoke the authorization of a deactivated admin (Manage Apps > Connected Apps OAuth Usage, click on the number in the User Count column) and reauthorize them as an active user.

Comment: Thanks @identigral, I only see an option to revoke the access but couldn't find an option to reauthorize? Can I reauthorize directly from Salesforce or do I have to log in to connected apps and reauthorize from third-party app with active admin creds?

Comment: You have to go through the 3rd party app.